# Resolvent Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hermitian matrix and $h$ some vector of the same length. The resolvent of $H$ at $z\in\mathbb C$ shall be denoted by $$G(z):=(H-z\cdot1)^{-1}.$$

Is it true that $$\frac{(\Im z)\left(1+\langle h,G(z)^2 h\rangle\right)}{z+\langle h,G(z) h\rangle}$$ 
is bounded in $z$?

Numerics suggest that this is indeed bounded in absolute value by $1$. Is this true? How could one prove this?

I thought about the following heuristic argument to study what happens for $z=x+iy$ with small imaginary part $y$. If $\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues and $u_n$ are the normalised eigenvectors of $H$, then $$G(z)=\sum_{n}\frac{1}{\lambda_n-z}u_n u_n^*\quad\text{and}\quad G(z)^2=\sum_{n}\frac{1}{(\lambda_n-z)^2}u_n u_n^*.$$ Therefore the above fraction reads $$\frac{y+\sum_{n}\frac{y}{(\lambda_n-x-iy)^2}\lvert \langle h,u_n\rangle\rvert^2}{x+iy+\sum_{n}\frac{1}{\lambda_n-x-iy}\lvert \langle h,u_n\rangle\rvert^2}$$ which tends to $0$ as $y\searrow 0$ if $x\not=\lambda_n$ for all $n$. Otherwise if, say $\lambda_n=x$ if and only if $n=1$, then the numerator approximately reads $$-\frac{1}{y}\lvert\langle h,u_1\rangle\rvert^2,$$ whereas the denominator is roughly $$\lambda_1+\frac{i}{y}\lvert\langle h,u_1\rangle\rvert^2$$ and therefore the limit is $i$, in particular bounded.

Comment: If I understand the setup correctly, if $H$ has an eigenvalue at zero, then your term would get $0/0$ for $z=0$ and $h$ being the corresponding eigenvector?